# What is the meaning of "pale and cold"? noun or adjective?

Tags: meaning, grammar, adjectives, nouns, articles

> ...Soon the **sharpened features**, and **sunken eye**, and fallen jaw, **pale and cold**, bearing the manifest impress of death's signet, began to glow with returning animation....

The source: [Leith in the time of cholera – the story of Thomas Latta](https://hekint.org/2017/02/01/leith-in-the-time-of-cholera-the-story-of-thomas-latta/#:%7E:text=Still%20persevering%20I%20thought%20she,small%20and%20quick%2C%20by%20degrees)

What is the meaning of "sharpened features"? why is "eye" a single form ? Why is not there "the“ or " a" before "fallen jaw"? what does "pale and cold" modify? what does "the manifest impress" refer to, pale and cold, or fallen jaw, or sunked eye?

I would think "pale and cold" is a noun refering the quality, and this quality is the manifest impress.

Comment: Grammatically, it should be "sunken eye". Is that a typo or in the original?

Comment: I suppose the writer is making the single _the_ serve for all three symptoms. Note that this was written 190 years ago. Shakespeare has Mistress Quickly say of the dying Falstaff "His nose was as sharp as a pen", presumably referring to pinched, shrunken features.

Comment: Why would you think that somebody must somehow be talking about *pales* and *colds* here? Although catching *colds* from time to time is unremarkable pre-Covid, most people don't even know what *pales* are.

Comment: You have asked six questions. The maximum is usually one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the meaning of "sharpened features"?

The impression of a face that's angular and bony because of disease.

> why is "eye" a single form ?

Because it can be, in poetic writing, and the style here is poetic and archaic.

> Why is not there "the" or "a" before "fallen jaw"?

Same reason.

> what does "pale and cold" modify?

All of the things before that were connected by "and", probably. It doesn't make much sense for it to just be "jaw".

> what does "the manifest impress" refer to, pale and cold, or fallen jaw, or sunked eye?

I wouldn't say it "refers to" any of them. "The manifest impress of death's signet" is a noun phrase, meaning "the visible signs of death" (a signet is a small [seal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_(emblem)#Signet_rings), usually attached to a ring, used to make an impression in wax. It's being used metaphorically here). "Manifest" is an adjective meaning visible or obvious, not a noun. The subject of the verb "bearing" is probably all of the things connected by "and" (features, and eye, and jaw, although features can stand for them all) and the object is "the manifest impress of death's signet".

Comment: Thank you every much.